# Fixing bugs in Android App

Tags: android, debugging, crash, crash-reports, crashlytics

I want you to know I'm a newbie to Android Development.

I have developed an Android application (not uploaded on Google Play Store) with [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) implemented.

This app is used by 50-60 users per day. Before releasing the app I tested it many times on my device and several others to check if it crashes or not. The app passed all the tests.

Now the app is crashing on some of the user's device and I can see the reason why it is crashing in Crashlytics dashboard.

But the app is crashing on specific devices only and working fine on other user's device and even after reproducing the issue on my device the app does not crash so I'm a bit confused about how to tackle problems like this.

And I can not purchase a device just for the purpose of testing.

So my questions are,

1. How can I solve the bugs in my app which are not reproducible on my devices?
2. Is it possible to know the exact reason why the app crashed using other bug reporting tools so that I can reproduce the bug on my device.

Any help is appreciated 
Thank You :)

Comment: Why don't you just use emulators for testing?

Comment: You may also try online device farm like AWS Device Farm.

Comment: Try [TestFairy](https://testfairy.com/) also

Comment: First you should check the android versions of the devices on which your app is crashing then you  can use "GenyMotion" to test accordingly.

Comment: @Nongthonbam Tonthoi I also tried it by creating the emulators of same configuration.

Comment: @hrskrs thanks, I will sure try these :). Hope these solve my problem

Comment: @Jiyeh it's not free :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow managed to fix bugs my app by using [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/). [Tracking an event](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android#sending_events) was so much helpful.

Thanks Guys. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). You can implement sending crash reports to your email which will have model of the phone, android version, and stack trace of the crash.

Comment: I'm also getting the same data in Crashlytics

Comment: Then what else do you need to fix your app? You will have the complete stack trace like https://jpst.it/J2tC of where,why,which device the crash is happening with which you will be able to fix em. I hope this will help.

Comment: The problem is : app works on some devices and on some devices it crashes and I want to know why does it happen on those devices.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I had same problem like yours. Our testers/users with different devices, were able to send crash reports through mail (from ACRA) so that we can find the problems and fix them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very high chance that many bugs and performance issue might get missed out during testing. Using production level SDKs like [Finotes](https://finotes.com) or [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) to capture bugs with a detailed report which makes it easy to do the root cause analysis.

Crashlytics captures only crashes, Finotes captures many other types of bugs as well. Both SDKs are so lightweight and don't affect apps performance in production.